# Extract some JSON contained in an XML in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml

I'm trying to extract some JSON contained in  of my XML file and then retrieve the values.

My XML is :

```
<Vehicle xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://regcheck.org.uk">
  <vehicleJson>{
  "Description": "RENAULT SCÉNIC III",
  "RegistrationYear": "2016",
  "CarMake": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "RENAULT"
  },
  "CarModel": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "SCÉNIC III"
  },
  "EngineSize": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "5"
  },
  "FuelType": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "DIESEL"
  },
  "MakeDescription": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "RENAULT"
  },
  "ModelDescription": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "SCÉNIC III"
  },
  "Immobiliser": {
    "CurrentTextValue": ""
  },
  "IndicativeValue": {
    "CurrentTextValue": 0
  },
  "DriverSide": {
    "CurrentTextValue": ""
  },
  "BodyStyle": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "MONOSPACE COMPACT"
  },
  "RegistrationDate": "2016-06-24",
  "ImageUrl": "http://immatriculationapi.com/image.aspx/@UkVOQVVMVCBTQ8OJTklDIElJSQ==",
  "ExtendedData": {
    "anneeSortie": "2016",
    "boiteDeVitesse": "",
    "carburantVersion": "D",
    "carrosserieVersion": "",
    "classeSra": "",
    "libVersion": "1.5 dCi 1461cm3 110cv ",
    "libelleModele": "SCÉNIC III",
    "marque": "RE",
    "modele": "",
    "produit": "",
    "puissance": "5",
    "version": "",
    "cleCarrosserie": "",
    "groupeSra": "",
    "nbPlace": "5",
    "datePremiereMiseCirculation": "24062016",
    "questionBatterie": "",
    "electrique": "",
    "genre": "",
    "typeVehicule": "",
    "numSerieMoteur": "VF1JZ890H55864144",
    "valeurANeufSRA": "",
    "niveauRisqueVol": "",
    "protectionConstructeur": "",
    "puissanceDyn": "110",
    "segmentVeh": "",
    "KtypeId": "5853",
    "EngineCC": "1461",
    "Co2": "105",
    "Cylinders": "4",
    "CNIT": "M10RENVP472E768"
  }
}</vehicleJson>
  <vehicleData>
    <Description>RENAULT SCÉNIC III</Description>
    <RegistrationYear>2016</RegistrationYear>
    <CarMake>
      <CurrentTextValue>RENAULT</CurrentTextValue>
    </CarMake>
    <CarModel>SCÉNIC III</CarModel>
    <BodyStyle>
      <CurrentTextValue>MONOSPACE COMPACT</CurrentTextValue>
    </BodyStyle>
    <EngineSize>
      <CurrentTextValue>5</CurrentTextValue>
    </EngineSize>
    <NumberOfDoors>
      <CurrentValue>5</CurrentValue>
    </NumberOfDoors>
    <Transmission>
      <CurrentValue />
    </Transmission>
    <FuelType>
      <CurrentTextValue>DIESEL</CurrentTextValue>
    </FuelType>
    <Immobiliser>
      <CurrentTextValue />
    </Immobiliser>
    <NumberOfSeats>
      <CurrentValue>5</CurrentValue>
    </NumberOfSeats>
  </vehicleData>
</Vehicle>
```

Step 1: I'm looking to retrieve the Description and some values ​​contained in ExtendedData :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($my_xml) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$infos_plaque = json_encode($xml->vehicleJson); // The attribute where the JSON is stored
$array = json_decode($infos_plaque);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

This $array return :

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [0] => {
  "Description": "RENAULT SCÉNIC III",
  "RegistrationYear": "2016",
  "CarMake": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "RENAULT"
  },
  "CarModel": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "SCÉNIC III"
  },
  "EngineSize": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "5"
  },
  "FuelType": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "DIESEL"
  },
  "MakeDescription": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "RENAULT"
  },
  "ModelDescription": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "SCÉNIC III"
  },
  "Immobiliser": {
    "CurrentTextValue": ""
  },
  "IndicativeValue": {
    "CurrentTextValue": 0
  },
  "DriverSide": {
    "CurrentTextValue": ""
  },
  "BodyStyle": {
    "CurrentTextValue": "MONOSPACE COMPACT"
  },
  "RegistrationDate": "2016-06-24",
  "ImageUrl": "http://immatriculationapi.com/image.aspx/@UkVOQVVMVCBTQ8OJTklDIElJSQ==",
  "ExtendedData": {
    "anneeSortie": "2016",
    "boiteDeVitesse": "",
    "carburantVersion": "D",
    "carrosserieVersion": "",
    "classeSra": "",
    "libVersion": "1.5 dCi 1461cm3 110cv ",
    "libelleModele": "SCÉNIC III",
    "marque": "RE",
    "modele": "",
    "produit": "",
    "puissance": "5",
    "version": "",
    "cleCarrosserie": "",
    "groupeSra": "",
    "nbPlace": "5",
    "datePremiereMiseCirculation": "24062016",
    "questionBatterie": "",
    "electrique": "",
    "genre": "",
    "typeVehicule": "",
    "numSerieMoteur": "VF1JZ890H55864144",
    "valeurANeufSRA": "",
    "niveauRisqueVol": "",
    "protectionConstructeur": "",
    "puissanceDyn": "110",
    "segmentVeh": "",
    "KtypeId": "5853",
    "EngineCC": "1461",
    "Co2": "105",
    "Cylinders": "4",
    "CNIT": "M10RENVP472E768"
  }
}
)
```

Step 2: I try to retrieve the values ​​by making differents requests:

```
    print_r($array->Description);
    print_r($array->{'RegistrationDate'});  
    print_r($array->{'ExtendedData'}->{'puissance'});
    print_r($array->ExtendedData->puissance);

// or :   
          
    echo $array->Description;
    echo $array->ExtendedData->puissance;
    echo $array->ExtendedData->libVersion;
```

I think there is a problem while encoding the Json, I have tried differents solutions but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to **decode** the JSON into a PHP data structure. Then you can access its properties

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($my_xml);
$data = json_decode($xml->vehicleJson); //  just decode the string

echo $data->Description;
echo $data->ExtendedData->puissance;
echo $data->ExtendedData->libVersion;
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/ZjE9H